# How do we know orbitals of atoms and elements exist?

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

How would we know if we have never experimentally seen them?

Comment: They don't. They are mere figments of our imagination which just happen to come in handy.

Comment: Also, we've seen them experimentally (for example: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38605/why-is-it-possible-to-image-lumo-if-these-orbitals-are-by-definition-unoccupie). How so, would you ask? A contradiction? Well, quantum stuff is ***weird***.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin I don't understand whether you are bung sarcastic or serious

Comment: Then you still underappreciate the weirdness of quantum mechanics. Who said I can't be both?

Comment: Nobody says that orbitals exist. But calculations made with them explain correctly the real chemistry like the shapes of molecules.

Comment: @Maurice At least (although I am not authoritative at all :) I am not saying that. Perhaps that applies to orbital as reserved to wavefunctions, certainly not to the quantities can be derived from. The linked paper on pentacene speaks for all.

Comment: Its just for our understanding ..its a tool